# Why my deployed react-app is showing a blank page

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, vercel, github-pages-deploy-action

Why is that the react app I deployed via github pages is showing a blank page. I tried doing this already before (using the default react-homepage only for testing purposes) and it worked just fine.

```
"homepage": "https://aaroncferrer.github.io/banking-app",


"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build",


"gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
```

I was able to add/install the dependencies above as well.
This was my reference for deployment instructions: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages#2-create-a-react-app

Repo link: https://github.com/aaroncferrer/banking-app

Additionally, I tried deploying the react app via vercel but it also gives me an error upon deployment/building phase:
[Vercel Depoloyment Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SYj8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should have the index.html file in the main root of your application and not in any other folder like public. Hope this resolves the issue

Comment: But when I tried doing a sample deployment I didn’t need to move index.html from public to the root folder and it worked just fine.